# How to set title of the uploaded video on Vimeo?

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

This is the code I use to upload video on Vimeo:

```
require('vimeo.php');

$config = array(
    'client_id'     => 'XXX',
    'client_secret' => 'XXX',
    'access_token'  => 'XXX'
);

$lib = new Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret'], $config['access_token']);

$uri = $lib->upload('video.avi');
$video_data = $lib->request($uri);
```

**vimeo.php** is this file: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/vimeo.php

How should I change the title of the video once it's uploaded?

Answer (score 5):

You want to make a PATCH request to the new video uri, providing a "name" in the body. It should look something like this:

```
$lib->request($uri, array(
    'name' => $title
), 'PATCH');
```

**Note: API 3.4 allows you to provide your video title during the upload process. As of December 14th, 2017 API 3.4 is in closed beta. It will become public in January 2017**

Comment: and make sure that you have edit Scopes while getting access token.

Comment: +1, just saved me. Couldn't figure out why I was getting gibberish back from the Vimeo server until I found this and changed from 'POST' to 'PATCH'.